# Floating image overlaps container. Clearfix hasn't worked

Tags: css, clearfix

I have literally been trying every clearfix hack that I could find for hours and nothing is working. The paving photo at the bottom right always goes outside the content container. This is currently what I have:

```
.content {
    margin: -10px auto 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    }

#paving_photo {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.content:after { 
content: "";
display: block;
height: 0; 
clear: both; 
}
```

This is the page: [website template](http://www.gallantrywebdesign.com/hajjpavinganddemo/)

I have tried the clearfix hack and micro hack. I have added the clearfix to the content class. I have tried overflow: hidden|auto. I have tried adding the clear: both after the floating element. Literally nothing as worked.

I'm at my wits end. Please help! 
Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I should add that the problem seems to only appear in Safari and FF. It seems to be fine in IE.

Comment: what size (in pixels) is your screen?

Comment: My screen at home is 1440 x 900.

Comment: I've posted that as my answer...

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine on FF on my end, with the exception being when the screen height is less than about 791px. I think this is due to `.outercontainer` height is set to `height:100%`.